# Old Tomcat - Java - Ant project recovery

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, setup-project, disaster-recovery

I need some advices in order to get what to do and how to understand a pretty broken project that I've never seen.
It's a Java 5 project with servlets and jsp and looks like it's been built in ant.

It was updated many times from a lot of different people. I've tried to launch the ant build.xml script where this part should build it (others are referring to libraries, not important I guess).

```
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src/xxx_src"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/00_hibernate"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/00_jblooming"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/00_jblooming_waf"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/00_svn"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/05_designer"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/20_indexing"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/40_website"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/42_forum"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/50_core"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/52_flowork"/>
        <src path="src/yyy_src/88_JES_mailserver"/>
        <classpath refid="xxx.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
```

I distinguish between XXX and YYY because it's kinda 2 different project. Intellij detects as 2 different packages. No idea about how this ever worked.
By running this it creates an "out" directory but no jar and not even .class files.
By running Tomcat (of course) the exception given is that is not able to find the main class. I'm a newbie and I'm pretty confused. The project structure is something I've never seen before.

[image: project_structure]

Inside utility we have Tomcat server and some images, for some reasons.
Inside src we have 2 dir "xxx_src" and "yyy_src" and in Intellij, it looks like this:

[image: intellij view]

Every directory that starts with numbers has an org or com directory which contains the logic.
Inside 50_core we have the Business logic and models, so the Java classes divided by sections. For example:

```
50_core/com/yyyproject/agenda/businessLogic/AgendaAction.java
50_core/com/yyyproject/agenda/businessLogic/AgendaController.java
50_core/com/yyyproject/task/Assignment.java
```

I need to make it run, but I don't really know how to proceed or where to look. Any advice helping me not to have an hearth attack would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> "By running this"

Ant consists of targets. A single script contains many targets and you have to specify one, e.g. `ant build` - which specifies 'run the `build` target'.

Which target did you run?

If you just type `ant`, and the top line of your ant file lists a default option (`<project name="something" default="some-target" ....>`) then that default is run.

This ant script is very incomplete; there are many targets with a description but which do absolutely nothing whatsoever, such as `build-subprojects`, so those things clearly do not work.

The basic idea of the project I can surmise from the bits you've pasted is this:

1. The project uses ecj - the eclipse compiler.
2. Instead of fetching ecj via the internet via e.g. [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) (an add-on for ant that lets you specify dependencies just by their name and version, and it will take care of downloading them from the web if needed), it... fetches them by finding them from your local eclipse installation.
3. Once those dependencies are in place, potentially together with any other dependencies in the `lib` dir checked straight into source control (you've pasted very little, I'm resorting to wild guesses here - note that checked binaries into source control is a bad idea), it can be compiled.
4. Compilation is relatively simple; take all the java files found anywhere in any sub(subsubsub)dir of any of those src dirs listed at the top of your snippet and compile them all, but they go to the `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` directory (relative to where the `build.xml` file is). Your snippet does not include making that directory, so this too will fail unless that directory is already there. It might be, perhaps that too was erroneously checked into source control.

So, to recreate this build step by step:

1. Download the oldest version of eclipse you can find.
2. Fetch the org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar file from there.
3. copy it over. Also, unzip just the file `jdkCompilerAdapter.jar` which is apparently inside it, so that it sits next to that jdt.core jar file.
4. do the `<javac>` task by hand. Just.. look at it, surely you can read that.
5. Note that this project had an alternative build task where the eclipse compiler is used to compile it instead of the javac compiler. This is weird - the primary benefit of the ecj compiler is that it is properly open source (unlikely to be the concern), faster (I doubt that was the reason), and usually more correct (but that would imply the sources were so exotic, javac was erroneously failing to compile it. This can happen - back in the JDK1.5 days, `Integer x = 5; x++;` would crash javac for example, but that also sounds unlikely. Therefore, it probably isn't important, but if you get errors, that might be why.

Comment: I've tried to build it externally before figuring out it's generated from Eclipse! 
In command line I got this message
Complete build sequence is [build-subprojects, init, build-project, init-eclipse-compiler, clean, cleanall, build-refprojects, build, build-eclipse-compiler, ]
I tried to run every single target in order, but still not able to achieve a stable build. When I build (from Eclipse or Ant externally) I keep getting error message about missing libraries:
package javax.servlet does not exist
non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;

Comment: They told me it was updated to Java 8 for Tomcat 7 so I changed my JVM to 1.8.0_271. Eclise is able to build a WAR, tho. When I deploy it, Tomcat writes "C:\xampp\htdocs\code\pandora\utility\tomcat-startup-7\webapps" and then shutdown. I guess the war is uncomplete